# Writing SQL Query Lookup Activity in Synapse Pipeline Returns Error Message

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

When I try to create a view in Synapse using Lookup activity, it returns me an error.

The code I have is:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW view_name AS 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://datalake/container/Delta folder/', FORMAT='DELTA') AS result; 
SELECT 1
```

I'm receiving error message as:

> A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.' Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

The problem is I just need to create a view on top of delta files so it can be accessed by my SSMS and Power BI. (It seems right now if I just create table/views in Spark DB on Delta files, SQL on-demand can't query them.) That's why I'm using a lookup activity to execute the SQL Query.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding a `GO` statement after, as well as switching the order of the `SELECT` and `CREATE` statements (stupid attempt anyway), but the solution that works is to wrap the `CREATE` statement with `''`, using `EXEC` to execute it, and then doing the `SELECT 1`.

```sql
DECLARE @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLQUERY = 

CONCAT('CREATE OR ALTER VIEW <view_name> AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''https://','@{pipeline().parameters.DataLakeAccountName}','.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder_location>/'',
        FORMAT=''DELTA''
    ) AS [result]')

EXEC(@SQLQUERY)

SELECT 1
```

Note that I do have a pipeline parameter to set the datalake instance name, and that's why I'm using a parameter value inside my dynamic query generation piece.

Comment: That worked Amazingly thanks.!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW view_name AS SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://datalake/container/Delta folder/', FORMAT='DELTA') AS result

GO

SELECT 1
```

I’m not really sure why you need the `SELECT 1` part but that should work.

Comment: Hey the reason for having a select 1 is because lookup activity needs an output value eventually, so putting a select 1 to fool the activity itself. This method fails as well but I do find a workaround. I;ll put the answer down below myself